Can't install Solana CLI from Docker on a Mac
I've created a Dockerfile for Anchor development. Full code is here: https://github.com/foxreymann/SolanaAnchorDocker/blob/master/Dockerfile
The line to install Solana CLI:
RUN sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.anza.xyz/stable/install)"
works on two Linux machines but doesn't work on a Mac. Standard updated M1 Macbook.
The error is 404 when trying  to curl anything from anza.xyz domain. Please advise.

Can you give the exact URL that your Docker container is trying to access? Here is the releases page: https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/releases/tag/v2.0.18 -- if you're getting a 404, you might be trying to get a Linux aarch64 build, which is not provided currently

Yes, that was the problem. We had to force docker to install amd64 Linux.

Ok, 404 was at install bash script was trying  to download aarch64 Linux build that doesn't exists. We had to force Docker to install amd64 Linux on arm Mac. Then it works. You can check in the repo: https://github.com/foxreymann/SolanaAnchorDocker
